# Manga with a game tester who gets stuck in his game

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Please help me, I've been looking for this manga where the main character is a game tester testing the abilities in game, and he gets stuck in the game. I have already been looking for it for quite a time.

Comment: What sort of a game? What sort of abilities? It didn't happen to open with him using a cheat spell and wiping out an entire army and getting a ton of experience did it? Black and white? Color? Read on paper? Online? How did the translation look?

Answer (score 2):

Might it be *[Death March to the Parallel World Rhapsody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_March_to_the_Parallel_World_Rhapsody)*?

[image: Front cover of Death March to the Parallel World Rhapsody]

> Ichiro Suzuki is a 29-year old game programmer who was tasked with fixing several bugs in two MMORPGs his company is preparing for publication. However, he becomes extremely worn out as he is working during the weekend. After taking a nap, he mysteriously wakes up in a parallel world that resembles some of the fantasy RPG worlds he had worked on, as a 15-year old named Satou, later Satou Pendragon, a nickname he uses while running beta tests, and with what looks like the menu screen of the game he was working on appearing before his inner eye.
>
> However, before he can grasp his current situation, an army of lizardmen ambushes him and launches an all-out attack on him. In desperation, he uses all three of his special 'Meteor Rain' attack options (a quick fix he added to the game for new players which kills all enemies in the vicinity) at once and wipes them all out - accidentally killing a god as well. As a result, his level jumps from 1 to 310, maximizing his stats immensely and making him one of the most powerful people in the world. With no way to return to his world, and as a high-leveled adventurer armed with a myriad of different physical, cognitive and magical abilities and weapons, he sets out to uncover the secrets of this new world, earning the trust and affection of many people in the process while keeping his overpowered stats concealed.

Answer (score 1):

*[Sword Art Online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online)* is another possibility, although it s a bit more well-known.

[image: Front cover of Sword Art Online]

> In 2022, a virtual reality massively multiplayer online role-playing game (VRMMORPG) called *Sword Art Online* (SAO) will be released. With the NerveGear, a helmet that stimulates the user's five senses via their brain, players can experience and control their in-game characters with their minds. Both the game and the NerveGear were created by Akihiko Kayaba. On November 6, 10,000 players log into SAO's mainframe cyberspace for the first time, only to discover that they are unable to log out. Kayaba appears and tells the players that they must beat all 100 floors of Aincrad, a steel castle which is the setting of SAO if they wish to be free. He also states that those who suffer in-game deaths or forcibly remove the NerveGear out-of-game will suffer real-life deaths.
>
> One of the players named Kazuto "Kirito" Kirigaya, is one of 1,000 testers in the game's previous closed beta. With the advantage of previous VR gaming experience and a drive to protect other beta testers from discrimination, he isolates himself from the greater groups and plays the game alone, bearing the mantle of "beater", a portmanteau of "beta tester" and "cheater". As the players progress through the game Kirito eventually befriends a young girl named Asuna Yuuki, forming a relationship with and later marrying her in-game. After the duo discover the identity of Kayaba's secret ID, who was playing as the leader of the guild Asuna joined in, they confront and destroy him, freeing themselves and the other players from the game.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility yet is [Btooom!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btooom!)

More grounded than other examples, it feels closer to *squid game* than *SAO*

> Ryōta Sakamoto is an unemployed 22-year-old young man who lives with
> his mother Yukie. He is one of the world's top players of the combat
> video game called Btooom! One day, he awakes in what appears to be a
> tropical island, though he does not remember how or why he has been
> transported there. While wandering around, Ryōta sees someone and
> calls out for help. The stranger responds by throwing a bomb at him.
> Ryōta soon realizes that his life is in danger and that he has somehow
> been trapped in a real-life version of his favorite game.

Answer (score 0):

Was it "Quality Assurance in Another World"?

https://kodansha.us/series/quality-assurance-in-another-world/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should quote relevant portions of the content at the link you have given so this answer stands on its own if the link breaks someday.